# "Automatic" Language Change

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have included my navigation and footer using:

```
<?php include 'nav.php';?>
```

In my navigation I have language dropdown:

```
<ul class="language">
    <li class="en"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I make the link dynamic?
For example: If I am on page contact-us to redirect to /en/contact-us or when I am on page about-us to go to /en/about-us and so on..

Comment: htaccess is a good thing to research here.

Comment: no need for htaccess, when I can set simple php rules, for each page if on page example.php go to page en/example.php
But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: what.. you can do that in htaccess, why would you want your server language to handle URIs when it could just be your server?

Comment: what is your solution with .htaccess